# Unity API Returning Vector3s but the Values are Wrong

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

I'm using Replicate API to try and get a point cloud in Unity. I finally go the API returning a JSON file, and I'm pretty certain it's returning `vector3`s of the positions of each point. Yet, when I cast it to a vector3 the values get all out of whack, every number will be like, 6.852349e-43, and even some "NaN"s, when on the API they appear to be all values below 0.

here's what they look like on Replicate's page,

```json
  "coords": [
    [
      -0.039118800312280655,
      -0.25740715861320496,
      0.28050559759140015
    ],
    [
      0.13176295161247253,
      0.23972494900226593,
      -0.06013050675392151
    ],
```

Yet when I cast them to a `vector3` in Unity, they're returning like this,
[image: Broken Points]
I'm assuming I just shouldn't be casting them to a `vector3`? Replicate's page says ""coords" is an [N x 3] array of (X,Y,Z) point coordinates", and after extensive Googling, I have no idea what NX3 means. I've tried `float[,]`, `float[,,]`, and `float[][]` instead of `vector3`, but `vector3`'s the only one that ever gets assigned properly from the JSON file, (using `JsonUtility.FromJson`)

Here's my script calling the api,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using SimpleJSON;

public class Prompt
{
    public string prompt;
}

public class PostResponse
{

    public string completed_at;
    public string created_at;
    public string error;
    public string id;
    public Prompt input;
    public string[] logs;
    public string metrics;
    public Output output;
    public string started_at;
    public string status;
    public string version;

}

public class ReplicateAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions";
    private string REPLICATE_API_TOKEN = "r8_DhOE6C7LuA7edPvLh7Io0ukwbmXCLEY450vc3";

    [SerializeField] PointEResponse response;

    public string prompt = "dog";

    [SerializeField] Material material;

    [SerializeField] MeshFilter meshFilter;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Predict());
    }

    IEnumerator Predict()
    {
        string requestData = $@"{{
    ""version"": ""1a4da7adf0bc84cd786c1df41c02db3097d899f5c159f5fd5814a11117bdf02b"",
    ""input"": {{
        ""prompt"": ""{prompt}"",
        ""output_format"": ""json_file""
    }}
}}";

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(API_ENDPOINT, requestData);
        request.method = "POST";
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + REPLICATE_API_TOKEN);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error " + request.responseCode + ": " + request.error);
            StartCoroutine(Predict());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            PostResponse response = JsonUtility.FromJson<PostResponse>(request.downloadHandler.text);

            StartCoroutine(GetResult(response.id));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator GetResult(string id)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(API_ENDPOINT + "/" + id);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + REPLICATE_API_TOKEN);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");



        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error " + request.responseCode + ": " + request.error);
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            response = JsonUtility.FromJson<PointEResponse>(request.downloadHandler.text);



            Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
        }

        if (response.status != "succeeded") StartCoroutine(GetResult(id));
        else
        {

            if (response.output.json_file.colors != null && response.output.json_file.colors.Length > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.output.json_file.colors.Length; i++)
                {

                    GameObject g = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                    g.transform.localScale = Vector3.one / 100;
                    g.transform.position = new Vector3(response.output.json_file.coords[i].x, response.output.json_file.coords[i].y, response.output.json_file.coords[i].z);
                    Material m = new Material(material);
                    m.color = new Color(response.output.json_file.colors[i].x, response.output.json_file.colors[i].y, response.output.json_file.colors[i].z);
                    g.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = m;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(GetResult(id));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the "response" classes look like this,

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class PointEResponse
{
    public string id;
    public string version;
    public Urls urls;
    public DateTime created_at;
    public DateTime started_at;
    public DateTime completed_at;
    public string source;
    public string status;
    public Prompt input;
    public Output output;
    public object error;
    public string[] logs;
    public Metrics metrics;
}

[Serializable]
public class Output
{
    public JsonFile json_file;
}

[Serializable]
public class JsonFile
{
    public Vector3[] coords;
    public Vector3[] colors;

}

public class Urls
{
    public string get;
    public string cancel;
}

public class Metrics
{
    public float predict_time;
}
```

Where the output contains the coordinates and the colours of each coordinate. I'm assuming that I'm not supposed to be casting these to a Vector3, but I've tried everything else I know of any the only one that even returns any form.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: afaik what they mean by `N x 3` is just: a plain array with `float[N * 3]` where `N = amount of points` -> i should simply be a plain array

Comment: @derHugo Well, i thought it would be a 2D array, but I tried swapping out the Vector3 array for a float[ , ] and it never gets assigned. I tried float[], float[ , ], float[][], even tried Matrix4x4 to see if that would get me anywhere lol, but only the Vector3 gets parsed properly... Yet, it's not proper because the values are ocassionally NaN

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't see the JSON snippet you included .. that indeed rather looks like a `float[][]` to me .. the issue is that such a `float[][]` is not directly compatible using the built-in JsonUtiltiy which is limited to Unity's serializer which doesn't support complex collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you get here would not match a `Vector3` directly.

Afaik a `Vector3` is not directly JSON (de)serializable.

```
"coords": [
    [
      -0.039118800312280655,
      -0.25740715861320496,
      0.28050559759140015
    ],
    [
      0.13176295161247253,
      0.23972494900226593,
      -0.06013050675392151
    ],
```

means you get something rather looking like

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonFile
{
    public float[][] coords;

    // assuming same layout for those
    public float[][] colors;
}
```

If and how exactly this would be laid out in memory into a `Vector3` structs is dark magic I guess.

This type of complex collection however is also **NOT SPPORTED** by the built-in `JsonUtility`/Unity's Serializer!

You would rather need a third-party library such as e.g. `Newtonsoft Json.NET` which comes as a [package via Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2/manual/index.html)

using that instead you would go e.g.

```
using UnityEngine.Scripting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

[Serializable]
public class JsonFile
{
    public Vector3[] coords;
    public Color[] colors;
    
    // using a JsonConstructor you can directly here ensure your given Json data format is 
    // translated in usable types and structure
    // If this attribute is present Newtonsoft will automatically not directly assign the fields but rather use this constructor 
    // The [Preserve] is to ensure this constructor is not stripped of while building since nothing else will be ever using it
    [Preserve]
    [JsonConstructor]
    public JsonFile(float[][] coords, float[][] colors)
    {
        this.coords = new Vector3[coords.GetLength(0)];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.coords.Length; i++)
        {
            this.coords[i] = new Vector3(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
        }

        this.colors = new Color[colors.GetLength(0)];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.colors.Length; i++)
        {
            this.colors[i] = new Color(colors[i][0], colors[i][1], colors[i][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

and then go

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(request.downloadHandler.text);
```

---

btw since `Vector3` is a struct you an simply do

```
g.transform.position = response.output.json_file.coords[i];
...
m.color = nresponse.output.json_file.colors[i];
```

Comment: Well, you gave me an idea, actually. I used SimpleJson's JsonNode to manually assign the vector3s directly from the Json. JsonUtility just wasn't able to deserialize it properly
So, i just manually assigned them
                JSONNode node = JSON.Parse(request.downloadHandler.text);

                for (int i = 0; i < node["output"]["json_file"]["coords"].Count; i++)
                {
                    response.output.json_file.coords[i] = node["output"]["json_file"]["coords"][i];
                    response.output.json_file.colors[i] = node["output"]["json_file"]["colors"][i];

Comment: @Mashimaro7 that's of course another option if you want to go that route .. note though that this way of course you duplicate the processing work for parsing the JSON twice (once using JsonUtility and once using that SimpleJson). If this data (coords and colors) is actually **the ONLY** information you really care for then this might be a good alternative .. would still need to properly parse those from `float[]` to `Vector3` / `Color` of course

Comment: Thanks for your input, i would've never tried that if you didn't tell me JsonUtility couldn't parse Vector3s haha